# MechanicalSoup 2 submit buttons in form, provide time for the first to exert its effect or not?

Tags: html, forms, mechanicalsoup

The online HTML-form I want to fill out using MechanicalSoup has 2 submit buttons (so 1 form with 2 submit buttons). The first button (red in the picture "Toevoegen") is to upload a photo after choosing a file.[image] The second button (not shown) submits the completed form. I have figured out how to address the different buttons using the form.choose_submit() function, so that's fine.

My question now is the following:

When I fill the form by hand, I noticed that after selecting the file and pressing the first (red) button, it takes some time (1-2 secs) for the file to upload. When I now fill out the form using mechanical soup, do I have to include this time (1-2 secs) for the photo to upload (for example using the time.sleep()) before I (make MechanicalSoup) fill out the rest of the form and submit it using the second submit button? Or will the form figure out that it has to upload the pic first and wait for that before executing the final submit order? So it's really a timing issue I have to coordinate the proper functioning of both buttons...

I hope this edit clarifies things a bit more.

Thanks for any suggestions!!

If it helps: this is what I found in the HTML form for the first submit button:

```
<div id="edit-submitted-file_add-ajax-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-file webform-component--file_add">
        <label for="edit-submitted-file_add-upload">Add File</label>
        <div class="form-managed-file">
            <input type="file" id="edit-submitted-file_add-upload" name="files[submitted_file_add]" size="22" class="form-file" />
            <input class="button form-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submitted-file_add-upload-button" name="submitted_file_add_upload_button" value="Toevoegen" />
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted[file_add][fid]" value="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either you have 2 questions in one, or the title does not reflect your question at all (your question seems to be about file upload, not about 2 submit buttons). Please edit to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have one form with two buttons, or two forms?

Comment: I edited my question and hope it clarified stuff a bit. The question may be farfetched, but that's probably due to my ignorance...

Answer (score 1):

When submitting a file, the file upload is part of the form submission. There's no point waiting before submitting, because this is not when the file upload happens. Unless the website is seriously broken, there's no point waiting after either, because the `.sumbit()` method call is blocking, i.e. it returns only after the form submission, hence the file upload, is completed.

However, it's hard to tell what you should do exactly in your case: it seems the first submission is done without reloading the page, hence using JavaScript. MechanicalSoup does not do JavaScript, so it may or may not work (in a perfect world, sites that work through JavaScript have a non-JavaScript fallback, but ...).

Probably the best for you is to try and see what works.